# How do I generate multiple pages Box [1,2,3...] of [X]

Tags: forms, acrobat

I have a box label form and it all works great but we would like to be able to automatically generate sequential box labels.  So on the form we would have a [Total Boxes] form field.  If the user put in "5" then on the labels we would generate a different label for each box e.g. 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5, 4 of 5, 5 of 5.  I would be happy with this happening at the time they are printed, or generating a new PDF with all the pages.  Either way this needs to be a very simple process for the end user of the forms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a perfect solution to this in Acrobat.  I decided to simply recreate the form in Excel and lock the sheet except for the fields needed and then it was easy to create multiple pages.